# Button action segue doesn't work when prepareForSegue call in the same VC and VC contains tableView and anthers two segue action button

Tags: uitableview, swift3, xcode8, ios10, uistoryboardsegue

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

```
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath as NSIndexPath

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAddToChart", sender: nil)
}



 open override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath
    let product = products[indexPath.row]


    if (segue.identifier == "toAddToChart") {
        if  let viewController = segue.destination as? AddToOrderVC  {




        viewController.productName = product.productName
        viewController.productCode = product.productCode
        viewController.productType = product.productType
        viewController.productPrice = product.productPrice
        viewController.productDetails = product.productDescription
        viewController.pImageUrl = product.productimageUrl




    }
}

}
```

/when i remove prepareForSegue function from viweController its will work but when i apply it and after build the code i get thread 1:signal SigBArt error when another action segue button pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When let product = products[indexPath.row]
called out side of the segue with confirm identifier,it will beget an error so the  of this error is

```
 open override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let indexPath = self.selectedIndexPath



    if (segue.identifier == "toAddToChart") {
        if  let viewController = segue.destination as? AddToOrderVC  {

        let product = products[indexPath.row]

        viewController.productName = product.productName
        viewController.productCode = product.productCode
        viewController.productType = product.productType
        viewController.productPrice = product.productPrice
        viewController.productDetails = product.productDescription
        viewController.pImageUrl = product.productimageUrl




    }
}

}
```